# When to use API vs Nuget vs Internal Library

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, infrastructure

So I am trying to get more knowledge on the Architecture/Infrastructure of an application and want to build simple applications, just to learn.

So what I was wondering is the following:

If I have multiple applications which have functions that are almost same in every application, how can I move this code to 1 place and let all applciations use it.

Let's say the way of logging in. You preferably want to build it one time and maintain it at one place.  All updates should be done in one place.

Should I use an Api, nuget, shared library or something else?

The database for each application should be different.

This is a general question, but I am coding in C# .net

Comment: Yes., it is known problem that everyone “want to build logging”. Just do it couple times and get it out of your head :). But the question itself is not really suitable for SO or any other SE sites as it asks for opinions.

Comment: Agreed that it's not a good SO question.  In any case, the answer is _"It depends"_.  However, for a lot of what you are thinking about, NuGet is likely the way to go.  But... It depends

Comment: I don't mind getting opinions. That way I have different perspectives from different people and can choose the way which I find the nost suitable. The thing with nuget packages is that you need to keep the packages up-to-date within the projects itself. So for every (minor) change you need to update 10 applications